# Adding OSDs to Ceph with WAL+DB

Tags: ceph

I'm new to Ceph and am setting up a small cluster. I've set up five nodes and can see the available drives but I'm unsure on exactly how I can add an OSD and specify the locations for WAL+DB.

Maybe my Google-fu is weak but the only guides I can find refer to ceph-deploy which, as far as I can see, is deprecated. Guides which mention cephadm only mention adding a drive but not specifying the WAL+DB locations.

I want to add HDDs as OSDs and put the WAL and DB onto separate LVs on an SSD. How?!

Answer (score 0):

It seems for the more advanced cases, like using dedicated WAL and/or DB, you have to use the concept of [drivegroups](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/cephadm/drivegroups/#drivegroups)

Answer (score 0):

If the version of your Ceph is Octopus(which ceph-deploy is deprecated), I suppose you could try this.

`sudo ceph-volume lvm create --bluestore --data /dev/data-device --block.db /dev/db-device`

I built Ceph from source codes but I think this method should be supported and you could
try

`ceph-volume lvm create --help`

to see more parameters.